# WriteableBitmap equivalent for Windows Library for Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I want to use WriteableBitmap in my Javascript, but can't find it.
Does somebody know if there is an equivalent? I can't find any information on the Web.
I am developing for Windows Phone 8.1

I do capture a QrCode with help of the camera, save the picture as jpeg and want to decode it.

[**ZXing Example**](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#branches/WINMD/Clients/WindowsStoreJavaScriptDemo/js/default.js)

Comment: May be you need to use a canvas in HTML 5 and convert it to a bitmap using canvas.toDataURL(). What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I do capture a QR-Code with help of the camera and want to decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.  The Windows.Graphics.Imaging namespace has most of the image manipulations you may want to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.aspx
And there is a sample for manipulating images here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Imaging-Sample-a2dec2b0/sourcecode?fileId=44000&pathId=1293870845

Does that help?

-Jeff

Comment: Like i wrote. I want to capture a image and save it in the photo storage of my windows phone. Then i want to decode the picture with the help of the ZXing.net library. The library does need a Bitmap to decode the Qr-Code in the image. 
The BitmapDecoder is the solution. I've included a ZXing example, I've almost forgotten when i asked that question.
Hopefully it will help others...
Thanks for your answer